# How to install bind_member_variable.hpp in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boost, boost-spirit, ubuntu-16.04

I just fresh installed Ubuntu 16.04 and my project is not finding `bind_member_variable.hpp` anymore. In Ubuntu 14.04 it worked fine.

Where is the boost-spirit package in Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case,

```
apt-get install libboost-dev
```

If you want to be home free, just install all of boost:

```
apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

---

Note, I found this by doing

```
dpkg --search bind_member_variable.hpp
```

on a system that already had it.

Comment: I've installed that already. The problem seems to be the location of the file in different versions of boost. The project I'm trying to compile seems to be aware of this, and makes this test:
`#if BOOST_VERSION >= 106000
#include <boost/phoenix/bind/bind_member_variable.hpp>
#else
#include <boost/spirit/home/phoenix/bind/bind_member_variable.hpp>
#endif
`
But for some reason, in Ubuntu 16.04 I have `BOOST_VERSION 105800` and the file in `boost/phoenix/bind/bind_member_variable.hpp`, which should be only in `BOOST_VERSION >= 106000` according to test. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Wow you came from an ancient version then. Because I had checked several older versions. Note you can just include `phoenix.hpp`